# Searching user or searcher user?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

When I want to refer to the user who is performing a search, should I use "the searcher user" or "the searching user"?

Comment: You can refer to a person who is searching as a **searcher**.  *If the searcher is looking for values in a certain range...* but it is a lot more common to refer to the **search** itself, unless for some reason you need to refer to the user specifically.  A **search user** would probably be understood to refer to a user who is making use of the search *feature*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This US English speaker would use **searching user** or maybe **search user**.

*Searcher user* doesn't make sense because it sounds like the user is using something called a searcher, and that's not what we mean.

*Searching user* is a good choice because *the user is searching*.  We use this pattern of "present-participle noun" a lot (for example, in the title of the novel and movie [*The Running Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Running_Man_(novel))) to describe someone who is doing something at a specific moment.

Another possibility is to say *search user*; this means a user using something called "search", which is an accurate description.  It doesn't imply a particular user doing a search at this very moment, but is more general.  This pattern is often used in technical writing, for example

> [... the first of a series of search episodes needed by the search user in order to achieve his goal...](https://books.google.com/books?id=teVVuavsfvIC&lpg=PA128&dq=%22the%20search%20user%22&pg=PA128#v=onepage&q=%22the%20search%20user%22&f=false)

or

> [...search results are dynamically reformulated in order to more closely match the intent of the search user...](https://books.google.com/books?id=669CAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA668&dq=%22the%20search%20user%22&pg=PA668#v=onepage&q=%22the%20search%20user%22&f=false)